# determine whether combination of protein fragments might cover a complete protein sequence

Tags: python, bioinformatics

A FASTA file contains a single protein sequence. A second FASTA file contains sequences that are fragments of the sequence in the first file. Compute the molecular weight of each of the sequences, and using those, determine whether there is a combination of fragments that **may** cover the complete protein sequence, without those fragments overlapping

I've tried to make the following script, but I've not been able to put it all into a functioning code

So in

```
seqs
```

I've put the weight of the protein fragments, and in

```
total_weight
```

I've put the weight of the complete fragment, to test if the body I'm trying to use functions.

```
seqs = [50,70,30]
total_weight = 100
current_weight = 0
for weight in seqs:
    if current_weight + weight == total_weight:
        print(True)
    elif current_weight + weight < total_weight:
        current_weight += weight
    if current_weight > total_weight:
        current_weight -= weight
```

Obviously in this case I would want this code to return True. In order to solve this I'd like to omit the first element in the

```
seqs
```

list and then redo the 'for' loop I've made. Somehow I've not been able to complete the code by omitting the first element and running for loop again for the new

```
seqs
```

list. Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: You might be interested to know that there is a bioinformatics-focused Q&A site on the Stack Exchange network: http://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/. You'll get responses from a broader range of programmers here on StackOverflow, but on the BINFX site you'll get responses from folks who work with the relevant data types on a daily basis.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another recursion method that actually gives you any values in your list add up to 100, and will print out the new list, the statement `True`

```
seqs = [50,70,30]
total_weight = 100

def protein_summation_check(target, lst, newLst=[]):
    print(newLst)
    for index,protein in enumerate(lst):
        newLst.append(protein)
        protein_summation_check(target, lst[index+1:], newLst)
        if sum(newLst) == target:
            return ("True",newLst)
        newLst.pop()
    else:
        return False
print(protein_summation_check(total_weight, seqs))
```

For loop iteration that doesn't really work for all solutions, but will for the one you provided;

```
seqs = [50,70,30]
total_weight = 100
current_weight = 0

for index, item in enumerate(seqs):
    if  current_weight == total_weight or item == total_weight:
        print("True")
        break
    for otheritem in seqs[index+1:]:
        if otheritem == total_weight:
            current_weight = total_weight
            break
        if current_weight < total_weight:
            current_weight += otheritem + item
        if current_weight > total_weight:
            if otheritem >= total_weight:
                current_weight -= item
            else:
                current_weight -= otheritem
```

Comment: ```seqs = [15,100]``` won't match and you don't save item+otheritem so ```seqs = [30,30,40]``` won't match either

Comment: @IQbrod It checks for the first result that equals 100 and then breaks the loop, so only one `True` statement prints. Both `seqs = [15,100]` and `seqs = [0,15,100]` print `True` once. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by won't work.

Comment: ```if current_weight == total_weight``` should be placed before the second loop and you won't reset ```current_wieght``` each loop.  
```seqs = [15,100]``` does not match
```0 + 15 ? 15
| 15 == 100 ? False
| 15 + 100 ? Nothing
| 15 == 100 ? False
```

Comment: ```if current_weight > total_weight:``` will never reach as you won't add to ```current_weight``` if it's lower than total_weight.
You must also replace ```<``` by ```<=``` otherwise none will match

Comment: N+ combinations won't work either.
```seqs = [15, 70 ,80, 5]```
As 15 +70 + 5 will result in 90

Comment: Also you won't remember last current_weight value (as in recursive functions) in each loop, your method tries to add the first elements in the array to the current_weight but it might not be the solution (cf. prev)

Comment: I've been struggling to understand how the recursive function works, and can't see any patterns in the output. Could you maybe elaborate for the given example how the function works?

Comment: @SamVanbergen For the given recursive function, it takes three parameters (check value,list to iterate,empty list to append values to). Calling the function the first time starts the for loop and appends `50` to the empty list, then pauses the current function and makes a call to the function again, but this time with a slice of the list `[70,30]`, and appends `70` to the list, and this will continue until the end of the list, so it will make a total of  3 calls. After all calls have been made  `newLst = [50,70,30]`.

Comment: @SamVanbergen Since you are on the last call, it will check condition, if not `True` continue and remove last item resulting in `[50,70]`. Since the last call cannot iterate through the sliced list anymore, it will return and go to the 2nd call and do the same thing so it will continue where it left off, and check condition then remove item, resulting in `[50]` and go to the next item in the for loop which would result `[50,30]` it will then check condition and remove item if necessary and return the function when it exhausts the for loop and continue this pattern until finish all calls

Comment: @SamVanbergen If you need more explanation go to [Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197580/recursivefunction), Also marked as solved if I or anyone else has solved your question.

Answer (score 1):

Look into using permutaitons from itertools on your seq list:

```
from itertools import permutations 
perm_list = list(permutations(seqs))
perm_list
```

provides the following output:

```
[(50, 70, 30),
 (50, 30, 70),
 (70, 50, 30),
 (70, 30, 50),
 (30, 50, 70),
 (30, 70, 50)]
```

Then you can loop over those combinations indecies to see which values may equal the total weight.

Hope this is of use, Cheers!

Comment: You will generate ```n!``` rows for a n-vector which I assume as too consuming

Answer (score 1):

Your code obviously won't print True as

```
0 + 50 = 50
50 & 70 => Nothing happens
50 + 30 = 80
```

For each entry you might try to add next ones or don't, so your function will have two parameters, what's already grouped and the rest :

```py
def calculate(current: int, next: int[]):
  pass
```

You want to check if the current element is your total weight and if nothing can be added you won't get any further

```py
total_weight=100
current_weight=0
data=[50,70,30]

def calculate(current: int, next: int[]):
  if(current == total_weight):
    return True
  if(not next):
    return False
```

Now you check wether one of you calculation will result to your total

```py
def calculate(current: int, next: int[]):
  if(current == total_weight):
    return True
  if(not next):
    return False
  #Edit: x does not require to be calculated in every cases
  x = False
  if current+ next[0] <= total_weight:
    x = calculate(current+ next[0], next[1:]) #with
  y = calculate(current, next[1:]) #without
  return x or y

print(calculate(current_weight, data))
```

You might need thread to perform quicker and abort next calculation steps on big datasets